# Converting all nan values to zero in tensforflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert all `nan` values to zero in my final results. I am not able to execute it properly!

The following is the code: also availvable on colab : [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/194wjDGeaqnkpPnTtH8Sx_NyBtth5rUkX?usp=sharing)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ts = tf.constant([[0,0]]) 
tx = tf.constant([[0,1]]) 

out = ts / (ts + fx)

out.numpy() # array([nan,  0.])

tf.math.is_nan(out).numpy() # array([ True, False]

out.numpy()[(tf.math.is_nan(out).numpy())] = 0
out.numpy() #array([nan,  0.])
```

`out.numpy()` should give `array([0., 0.])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
out.numpy()[(tf.math.is_nan(out).numpy())] = 0
```

To:

```
out = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(out), 0., out)
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you route to this solution? I was also trying to search for this! This will be very helpful for me for the future!